# Is ssh-agent supposed to save passwordless identities after restarting Windows?

Tags: windows, openssh, ssh-agent

I'm using [OpenSSH for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_overview) on Windows 10 v1809. I've added an identity via `ssh-add` which required I enter the password for my encrypted key (`C:\Users\Me\.ssh\id_rsa`). I find that identity remains in `ssh-agent` after I restart Windows. Therefore, I can `ssh` to other machines without entering the key's password. In previous agents I've used, such as the one in MobaXterm (not OpenSSH), there was a master password used to unlock all keys saved to the agent. You had to re-enter that one master password after restarting.

Is this behavior in OpenSSH for Windows of no password being required after restart expected?

Perhaps I could write a script to `ssh-add -D` on Windows shutdown if don't want the identities to be saved?

Comment: I stumbled upon this today as well. And I'm not happy with that. Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: I found a issue/discussion on that on github: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1487

They have to remove that "feature". And i hope they will. 

ssh-add -D in a shutdown script didn't work for me. So still interested in a solution of yours.